# Getting the returned value of a function that has been decorated multiple times

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is there a way to get the returned value of my original function when using more that one decorator?
Here are my decorators:

```
def format_print(text):

    def wrapper():
        text_wrap = """
**********************************************************
**********************************************************
        """
        print(text_wrap)
        text()
        print(text_wrap)
    
    return wrapper

def role_required(role):
  
    def access_control(view):
    
        credentials = ['user', 'supervisor']

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
            requested_view = view()
            if role in credentials:
                print('access granted')
                return requested_view
            else:
                print('access denied')
                return '/home'

        return wrapper

    return access_control
```

When I run the function below with the @role_required I get what I was expecting:

```
@role_required('user')
def admin_page():
    print('attempting to access admin page')
    return '/admin_page'
x = admin_page()
print(x)
```

Returns:

```
attempting to access admin page
access granted
/admin_page
```

but when I uncomment the second decorator, admin_page() returns None

```
**********************************************************
**********************************************************

attempting to access admin page
access granted

**********************************************************
**********************************************************

None
```

Could someone maybe tell me where I am going wrong and how I would get the returned value from a function with multiple decorators.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you actually need do this:

```py
def format_print(text):

    def wrapper():
        text_wrap = """
**********************************************************
**********************************************************
        """
        print(text_wrap)
        result = text()
        print(text_wrap)
        return result
    
    return wrapper
```

Otherwise your wrapper will always return `None`.